Creating ISO from a linux computer
I've installed UBUNTU 24 on a stand alone pc and installed some software on it with specific configuration.
Now I would like to make a bootable ISO from this pc to a USB.
The main goal is to have a usb I can connect to a new stand alone pc and it will open this ISO to the new pc so I can just reboot and start working with it just like the the original pc.
Is this something I can do?
(Using Ubuntu 24 on the original pc, The size is about 6 Giga)
Thanks.

Your question isn't clear. Please use the EDIT link below the question to add clarification.
Specifically: Do you intend to use this USB stick as a portable installation that you can use with other computers? Or is this a 1-time-only action to transfer your current system to a different computer? Answers will differ a lot based on that information. (And in both cases a bootable ISO is probably not suitable.)

This question is similar to: How do I install linux to a usb for portability and booting on any UEFI machine?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Do you want to create an ISO, or do you want to create an image of the existing system so you can easily replicate it on another system? It sounds to me that you're wanting the latter. Please reconsider what you are asking, and EDIT your question to make it more clear and possible changing your phrasing to confirm what you are actually asking.

In most cases, it is not feasible to copy an operating system verbatim from one machine to another because the fully installed operating system likely does not have all the drivers needed for a different PC.
*It is feasible if the two PC's are identical, not just make and model, but internally (manufacturers make changes on PC's as time passes, for example, when a source of a particular NIC dries up, or is replaced by a newer model).
However, you can make installation media, e.g., USB flash drive or external SSD, with persistence, and run that on virtually any PC. Caveat: ordinary flash drives are f a r   t o o   s l o w to make using them for the OS enjoyable. An external SSD should be better.

Linux is generally pretty forgiving about hardware differences during the initial boot process, assuming a single drive computer you can typically move that drive to a different system and most of the time it will boot - at a minimum to a text console (you may not get X11 or networking) but you typically have an operational enough system to get it connected to the network and once thats done, you can download anything else you need to get your system fully up and running again. TL;DR if it boots your golden anything else you can fix.

@DavidT, in general I agree... but I've at least one PC for which I had to install a Linux NIC driver -- downloaded from another PC, obviously. Also, what if the display settings on the machine creating the boot USB are incompatible with the next? The installer, though, is more likely to succeed in booting on any device, so to make a portable OS, use the installer with persistence.

If a linux system can access it's storage it will typically boot, there are a limited number of common NIC chipsets on consumer hardware so Linux usually detects at least one - although you might need to configure it (set DHCP etc) worst case you would have to move a package using a USB stick, GUI/X11 support is more challenging, however the fallback text console has always worked (I have never seen the text console fail in 30 years of using linux).
